# Как стилизировать кнопку в CSS по изображению во вложении

Tags: css, css3, button

Как взаимно расположить фоны бекграунда так, чтобы слева была иконка, затем разделительная линия и текст на градиентном фоне? Вот что должно получиться:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
input.fb {
  background:
     url(images/fb-icon.png) no-repeat,
     linear-gradient(#0d76be, #0d63ab),
     linear-gradient(to left, #0d63ab, #000),
     linear-gradient(to left, #0d63ab, #0d63ab);
  background-position: ???;
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #0d63ab;
  }
```

```html
<form><input class="fb" type="submit" value="Login with facebook"></form>
```

Comment: покажи свою разметку, посмотрим что можно сделать

Comment: https://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-social/ Тут есть иконки ВСЕХ социальный сетей(вк и одноклассники тоже). Следуйте инструкциям и наслаждайтесь жизнью.

Comment: @AlexeyDolgov Такое пишут в ответах.

Comment: Не получается после иконки нарисовать линию, чтобы отделить value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Извините, но шрифт и иконку не стал подбирать:

```css
input.fb {
  width: 159px;
  height: 32px;
  
  background: 
    /* Иконка */
    url(images/fb-icon.png) no-repeat, 
    /* Черта (градиент может состоять из нескольких цветов с указанием позиции) */
    linear-gradient(to right, transparent 28px, rgb(9, 83, 144) 30px, transparent 30px), 
    /* Фон (самый нижний слой) */
    linear-gradient(#0d76be, #0d63ab);
    
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  border: 1px solid #0d63ab;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: right;
  font: 12.3px 'Trebuchet MS';
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(7, 18, 99, 0.9), 1px 1px 1px rgba(7, 26, 99, 0.75);
}

body { background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM2vD.jpg) no-repeat 172px 3px; }
```

```html
<form><input class="fb" type="submit" value="Login with Facebook"></form>
```